# Run local service over HTTPS

Tags: ssl, service, https, ssl-certificate

I have a website served over HTTPS. I need this site to be like this as it is configured to work with service workers.

This website needs to request some information from a local service running in the organization, but the problem is that this local service has a self-signed certificate and so chrome denies the connection.

The idea of this website is that if you get into it from an organization, it should show some information and if you get into it from an other organization you should see another information. It depends from where you get into the site.

The problem is that each organization has its own network and so in one organization this service might be running at 192.168.1.106 and in an other organization this service could be at 10.0.1.9.

The question is: Is there a way to run this service over HTTPS? I dont want the user to install the certificate on his system.

Thank you!

Comment: I think [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com) is the right place to ask this question.

Comment: I replicated this question on ServerFault [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/857906/run-local-service-over-https).